# bool array vs bit array in C

Tags: c, linux

I am in need of implementing an efficient bit array in C. From what I have seen C does not support this so you can use an array of integers (according to one site I looked at) and then use a shift to access individual bits. Would simply declaring a bool array be the same thing or is this less memory efficient?

Comment: A `_bool` in C is generally an `int` internally. A `_bool[]` uses about 32 times (give or take) as much memory as the array of integers with bit-shifted access.

Comment: If using C++ is a viable option for you, std::vector<bool> offers the bit-packing space optimization you're describing.

Comment: @EOF: `_Bool` (not `_bool`) is typically 1 byte, not the same size as `int`.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Yeah, you're right. So it's just a factor of `CHAR_BIT`. I *said* give or take. You've just taken a lot...

Comment: Sadly C++ is not an option.

Comment: I will be using bit shifting so that I can store a flag in every bit of each int in the array. It seems that most everyone is in agreement though that _Bool is one byte so it will take up much more space than the int approach where a flag can be stored in every bite.

Comment: does storage space efficiency or speed matter more? accessing individual bits will be slower. a bit field may be worth considering

Comment: @camelccc: Memory bandwidth is more expensive than a couple of cheap logical ops on modern CPUs. Even L1 round trips can easily take ~6 cycles, while logical ops can be practically free on superscalar OoO CPUs. (On the other hand, these CPUs may have load/store-buffers that save the L1 roundtrip...Down the rabbit hole).

Comment: @EOF many modern CPU's explicitly state that L1 access is free and has no penalty vs register. The  Intel dwveloper manual explicitly states this. OP doesn't state his platform though, or why this isn't a premature optimization.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, a simple `_Bool` array require more storage than an array of integers combined with some bit-shifting. The `_Bool` array stores one bit of data in a `sizeof(_Bool)` space (normally a single byte).  The integer array can store many more bits per byte (minimum 8).